# How to test an authorize.net fraud transaction scenario in sandbox mode?

Tags: authorize.net

Authorize.net has a [fraud detection suite](https://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/frauddetectionsuite/). 
Is there a way to test it in sandbox/test mode of authorize.net? If yes, how? In the system we're developing we already added a handler for the scenario where authorize.net tells us the that transaction is a potential fraud. The problem is we don't know how to manually test the implementation in sandbox mode. We want to test it on sandbox mode first before we merge the code changes and deploy it to production.

As an additional info, we're using the activemerchant's [fraud_review?](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activemerchant/1.51.0/ActiveMerchant/Billing/Response#fraud_review%3F-instance_method) method for checking if authorize.net marks the transaction as a potential fraud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/testing_guide/, you can find a number of triggers that will enable you to generate error responses in the sandbox, by posting specific values for the Zip Code, CVV and Amount.

Comment: Only responses for AVS and CVV are there. And the transaction is not really being marked by authorize.net as potential fraud. What happens is authorize.net completely rejects the transaction. What we need is the scenario where authorize.net marks the transaction as potential fraud. But maybe we just need to edit some settings on authorize.net to mark the transactions as potential fraud (for cvv and avs) instead of rejecting the transaction. We'll check it...

Comment: Update: Your answer is correct. As an additional info: We need to turn on the fraud filters on the authorize.net sandbox website.